# textblock code trouble for date and time vb for windows

Tags: vb.net, date, time, windows-phone

Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
    Inherits Page

```
Private Sub textblock1_SelectionChanged() Handles textblock1.SelectionChanged
    textblock1.Text = Date.Now.ToString("MM/d/yyyy")
    textBlock2.Text = Date.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString("HHmmss")

End Sub
```

End Class

I wanted to make an windows app that displays the time (in hours:minutes:seconds) and the current date underneath in two text boxes since I could not get labels to show up in my toolbox. However, when I run this code, the Textblock text does not go to the time and date, but instead still reads 'TextBlock' and numbers appear in the top right '060 001' and in the top left '000 000'. What am I doing wrong?

This is an app for Windows 8.1, not Windows phone.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you... try to create a timer in your form. and inside your timer, copy this code... Don't forget to set the timer's property enable into "True"

```
     textBlock1.Text = Format(Now, "h:mm:ss tt")
     textblock2.Text = Format(Now, "MMMM d, yyyy")

End Sub
```